# Help identify what is breaking or eating the branches off my plants?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, tomatoes, pest-damage, cucumbers

I have tomato and cucumber plants, and I've observed a few broken branches. Initially, I attributed it to the weather, but it seems that even during a sunny week, more branches have been breaking off. Additionally, I've noticed a significant number of ants around the area, and in the mornings, birds tend to sit near my plants. I'm uncertain if they could be the cause of the damage. Or maybe unwanted pests? Do you have any insights or ideas about what might be happening?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like deer browsing damage given no broken branches on the ground, (so they are being eaten, not just broken off) and the prevalence of deer even in quite built-up areas. If not them, some other animal. If you have an obsolete cell phone or other inexpensive/"free" video camera it's easy enough to check.

I certainly consider deer an unwanted pest.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't even thought about deer being a potential issue. We do have quite a few deer in the area, although I haven't seen them around for a few months. Now that you mention it, there were no broken branches lying around, so it's possible the deer were responsible. I just assumed they were blown away. I'll construct some sort of barrier to keep them away and hopefully, that will help protect my plants.

Comment: Spray with undesirable tastes like garlic or soap, or sprinkle spices like black pepper around the soil. Keeps down on all grazing mammals like deer, rabbits, woodchucks.